# Tables, SQL C# Adding data to "FK table" by selecting a row in datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have **2** tables that have a `Datagridview`,
I want the second `datagridview` to fill up with data depending on which row that is selected on the first `datagridview`. I also want to filter it after `Column`, `Name`, etc.

(Add data to the second table in relation to first ID)
So I established a relation between these tables with `pk` and `fk`. I want to add Data to the second table by selecting value from the **first** table(by datagridview)

Comment: Add code what you have tried?

Comment: Well a lot..and i am kinda need a new on it. And everything i have is hopeless ..  made few foreach DataGridViewRows and try'd to work with the diff row. methods
without any success

Answer (score 0):

I always do following

1. I have an ID column (could be invisible) in the main DataGridView
2. I use CellClick event to fire a LoadDetail() sub
3. In the LoadDetail() sub I use DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("ID").value parameter (providing your DGW is in FullRowSelect mode), but you could also pass it as a parameter (Me.DataGridView1.rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ID").value) in the above CellClick event function.
4. LoadDetail() is a standalone sub which loads detailed data for the selected row depending on the selected row or given parameter. This way, it can also be used for a "Refresh" button or for automatic updates, i.e. after saving changes.

If you wanted to update the second DataGridView based on shifting rows by arrows, you have to use KeyUp in a similar fashion.

The FK can help in the SQL query, but I think is not important for the way you handle loading of the second DataGridView.

Comment: I finally got it together. I did the sync between table 1 and table 2 by grabbing the id cell value from each row in table 1, with it i just made some sql querys for filling up table 2 depending on what was showing in table 1

Comment: Good :-). It's rather simple, once you get your little way through it...